# Alter table SQL command in wordpress

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, alter-table

Due to some changes in the DB of my plugins, I need to alter a table to add some columns to it, but even though the function is running, the table isn't altered. Here's the function that I've written

```
    $sql = "ALTER TABLE `wp_tnt_videos` ADD `date_created` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' AFTER `video_order`, ADD `date_modified` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' AFTER  `date_created`, ADD `user_id` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' AFTER `date_modified`;";

    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
    dbDelta($sql);
```

I read this: http://hungred.com/how-to/wordpress-dbdelta-function/ 
And tried to check sql command carefully. I also run that sql command in mysql and it work!! 
So, please help me! :|

Comment: do u have an alter permission using current password and username

Comment: I am developing on localhost and my account is root. I use XAMPP and never change password of mysql.

Comment: You should read more this article: http://hungred.com/how-to/wordpress-dbdelta-function/ . dbDelta is a picky function. :|

Comment: it seems that you should not use such functions which has no documentation.

Comment: No, have document for this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins#Adding_an_Upgrade_Function . But not engough :|

Answer (score 4):

Your answer is in the Codex:

> - You must put each field on its own line in your SQL statement.
> - You must have two spaces between the words PRIMARY KEY and the definition
>     of your primary key.
> - You must use the key word KEY rather than its synonym INDEX and you must include at least one KEY.
> - You must not use any apostrophes or backticks around field names.
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins#Adding_an_Upgrade_Function

For one, you've got backticks around field names. That rule probably applies to table names too but I am not sure.

Additionally, you are trying to use `dbDelta` as if you were making a direct query to the database. It doesn't work that way. You need to give it the complete desired table structure using `CREATE TABLE` as if you are creating new every time and ...

> The dbDelta function examines the current table structure, compares it
>   to the desired table structure, and either adds or modifies the table
>   as necessary, so it can be very handy for updates (see
>   wp-admin/upgrade-schema.php for more examples of how to use dbDelta).
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins#Adding_an_Upgrade_Function

You don't give it `ALTER TABLE` commands or feed it just the parts you want to change. It is not a general purpose database alteration tool in that way. And, as already mentioned, it is very picky. Format your SQL exactly like in the examples, line breaks included.

I would add that you need to watch this function very carefully. It fails silently and seems to not what to do certain things, like delete indexes-- at least I have had a lot of trouble with that. I am not sure if it will move columns around to insert new ones or just add to the end.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to execute your SQL command like that :

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query($sql);
```